# How to make 0 number value show a zero instead of a white space?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function.  What I want to do is pass a four digit number to this function and the function will generate another four digit number that when added to the number that called the function each digit added to it will add up to nine.  But if a digit in the calling number is a nine, my function can only add a zero but when printed the zero is just a white space.  For example, if the calling number is 9988 I want my function to return 0011 but it really returns 11

Here is the function:

```
def make_nine(user_num):
    '''generates a number that when added to the users number sums up to 9'''

    make_num_nine = []
    for num in str(user_num):
        num = 9 - int(num)
        make_num_nine.append(num)
    return int("".join(str(x) for x in make_num_nine))
```

Comment: Just return a string instead of casting to an int. edit: look at Blender's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`0011` is `11`. Leading zeroes are discarded, so if you want to preserve them, return a string:

```
return "".join(str(x) for x in make_num_nine)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to return the string '0011' instead of the value 11, omit the int() in the last line.

Or if you want to print an integer with leading zeros, use `'{:04}'.format (i)`.

An easier way to implement your function would be:

```
def make_nine(user_num): return '{:04}'.format (9999 - user_num)
```

Hence, your program with user input, calculation and output could be written as:

```
print ('{:04}'.format (9999 - int (input ('Your number: ') ) ) )
```

And no quotes around the output, as those seem to annoy you.

Comment: You can just use `str(9999 - user_num).zfill(4)`

Answer (score 1):

Your last line returns an int.

This will remove leading zeroes, as they are non-significant.

Try `return ''.join(str(x) for x in make_num_nine)`. That should do it.

Edit:

If you really, really, *really* want Python to write out the '0011' without the quotes, try this:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as w:
    w.write(make_nine(9988))
```

Comment: That works but it displays '0011' with the quotes and I don't want the quotes.  I want it to appear like 0011

Comment: Does it display it in the python shell? If so, use `print` to output the result. There is no number 0011, only a number 11. 0011 will always be a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're returning it as an int. If you have leading 0's, they won't be included. If you want to print the return value as a 4 digit number, you can use [the string format function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) as follows:

```
input = 9988
output = make_nine(input)
print "{0:0>4}".format(output)
```

If you want to generalize this to n-digit inputs, you can do the following (format specifier within a format string, to specify the width):

```
input = 9988
output= make_nine(input)
print "{1:0>{0}}".format(len(str(input)), output)
```

Of course, it might make sense to just leave the output of the function as a string, depending on your application.